# How to pass JSON object as parameter from Postman to ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to pass json object as a query string parameter (not from body) to ASP.NET Core Web API url from postman.
Kindly let me know how to pass?
below the sample JSOB object structure :

here, 'names's is string array

```
"students":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "names":["john", "james"]
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "names":["peter", "harry"]
     }
]
```

Comment: I think you would have to base64 encode the value and send it as one parameter but that would mean refactoring the controller to decode and deserialize it

Answer (score 3):

This is a demo I made , you could refer to

In Postman , remember to set "**Content-Type**" to "**application/json**" in the **Headers**, otherwise you might get a error - 415 Unsupported MediaType.

```
https://localhost:44388/api/student/?students[0].id=1&students[0].name[0]=john&students[0].name[1]=james&students[1].id=2&students[1].name[0]=peter&students[1].name[1]=harry
```

The Student Model

```
 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Name { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller , do not forget add **[FromQuery]** in the parameter of action.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostStudent([FromQuery]List<Student> students)
    {
    }
}
```

The screenshot of students parameter

[image]

As Gabriel Luci said ,the Json object is best passed in the body of request.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using this in a GET (otherwise there is no point in doing this). I will also assume you want the `students` parameter of the URL to be set to that array.

You have to URL encode the whole string. You can use an online encoder like https://www.urlencoder.org to do it. That will take this:

```
[{"id":"1","names":["john","james"]},{"id":"2","names":["peter","harry"]}]
```

And turn it into this:

```
%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%22john%22%2C%22james%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%22peter%22%2C%22harry%22%5D%7D%5D
```

So that's what you'd put in your URL:

```
http://example.com?students=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%22john%22%2C%22james%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%22peter%22%2C%22harry%22%5D%7D%5D
```

But I hope this shows why no one does this :) It's messy and it can get really long really fast.

The answer by @RomanMarusyk is a little more civilized, but the signature of your controller needs to match it: you would accept a `List<Student>` (or whatever your student class is called).

Ideally, JSON objects like this should be in the body of the request, and you would use an HTTP method that accepts a body (like POST or PUT).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
?students[0][id]=1&students[0][names][0]=john&students[0][names][1]=james&students[1][id]=2&students[1][names][0]=peter&students[1][names][1]=harry
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in Addition of **Xueli Chen** Answer I tested it in **.net core2.2**

The Student Model

```
 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Name { get; set; }
}
```

In Postman ,set "Content-Type" to "application/json" in the Headers and also set `[Produces("Application/json")]` on controller Side
In Controller , If you dont use **[FromQuery]** in the parameter of action it will also work and i think it just Extra type Casting and it i will use resources for conversion also. If we dont use it will also work and i change of parameter why are you getting List of students in parameter it will aslo word without it.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostStudent(Student students)
    {
          // you can get data here from students objects
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case we must send only this json:[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "names":["john", "james"]
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "names":["peter", "harry"]
     }
]